# What elements of Teleglitch are random?

Tags: teleglitch

Being a roguelike, teleglitch has an element of randomness to each playthrough. As I'm thinking about planning my next run I want to know if I should skip certain map sections I'm familiar with.

What elements are randomized? Item containers? Enemy spawns? Anything else I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item containers (placement and items) are randomized, enemy spawnpoints are randomized, map is randomized.
Map is constructed out of rooms that are then connected into a level.

You can't really plan for a run as there are very few constants.